# Bug when using Plot3D over an ImplicitRegion?

Tags: plotting, regions

Evaluating this expression seems to cause Mathematica to beep and quit the kernel:

```
Plot3D[Exp[Sqrt[x^2]] - Exp[-Sqrt[x^2]], {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[-5 <= x <= 5 && -5 <= y <= 5 , {x, y}]]
```

I am running Mathematica 10.0.0 on MacOS 10.9.4. Is this a known issue?

Interestingly, plotting only one of the exponentials rather than their difference does not produce any problems.

Comment: Yes, that's a bug and it seems fixed in the development version. So, hopefully it will make it into a bug fix release soon. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in version 10.3

Comment: @JasonB I can't reproduce the issue on 10.1 or later.